# How to compare serialize arrays using wp post meta query IN operator?

Tags: wordpress

Can you please help me. How can I use `IN` compare operator of wp post meta query to compare a serialized array value in post meta key?
The serialized array is in digits and I want to use `IN` to compare values.
Thanks.

Comment: Explain the data that is saved in the postmeta table and the conditions you want to use to retrieve that data.

Comment: Data store in post meta table like this
a:20:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:2:"27";i:2;s:2:"28";i:3;s:2:"29";i:4;s:2:"30";i:5;s:2:"34";i:6;s:2:"35";i:7;s:2:"36";i:8;s:2:"37";i:9;s:2:"64";i:10;s:2:"54";i:11;s:3:"154";i:12;s:3:"155";i:13;s:3:"156";i:14;s:3:"157";i:15;s:2:"50";i:16;s:2:"51";i:17;s:3:"103";i:18;s:3:"104";i:19;s:3:"105";}

Comment: And what kind of conditions do you want to check on that data?

Comment: And this is my wp post meta query
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array('properties'),
  'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'meta_query'        => array(
      'relation'  => 'AND',
      array(
         'key' => 'ps_attributes_array_check',
         'value' => implode(',', $attribute), //array
         'compare' => 'IN',
      )
    ) 
);
$Property_list = new WP_Query( $args );

Comment: Is it possible with the serialize array to compare multiple id using wp post meta query or i will store data in other way?

Comment: yes you can save the attributes in multiple rows and then run IN query as shown in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot run a IN check on serialized data because Mysql sees it as a string. However, you can run a LIKE query to check whether the values are in there.

Following might not be a perfect solution but it should do the trick.

```
if (count($attribute) == 1) {
    $query['ps_attributes_array_check'] = array( 'key' => 'ps_attributes_array_check', 'value' => "\"$attr\"", 'compare' => 'LIKE' );
} else if (count($attribute) > 1) {
    $query['ps_attributes_array_check']['relation'] = 'OR';
    foreach($attribute as $attr) {
        $query['ps_attributes_array_check'][] = array( 'key' => 'ps_attributes_array_check', 'value' => "\"$attr\"", 'compare' => 'LIKE' );
    }
}
```

**Update**:
If you save the attribute IDs in separate rows instead of serializing the data, you can run the following query:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'ps_attributes_array_check',
        'value' => $attribute,
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
)
```

Comment: Is it working? Can you please add whole post meta query please

Comment: This will work only once you've converted from serialized data to multi-row. Once that is done, replace your meta_query with mine.

Comment: Is it a good way to store value in seperate rows because in a one post if i select 20 attributes then 20 rows added in post meta table.

Comment: Can you please suggest me?

Comment: It’s not the best method, but it is easier to query and get correct results. But if you are going to have say about 200 posts, then that is something you can work with.

Comment: If you are open to using other options you can create a separate table and save the data in JSON column. Newer versions of MySQL provide a JSON type and allow you to query on that directly.

Comment: No might be 500 or 1000 plus posts created